# Generate select option based on the number of selected

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have one selection option which display value 1 to 5. Based on the value selected, it will generated select option based on the number selected. let say i select 3, then it will generated 3 select option. Its possible to loop the ajax in jquery something like this
Here is my div

```
<select name="noAffected" class="form-control noAffected" id="noAffected" required>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group affectedsec1" id="affectedsec1">
<div>
<div class="form-group affectedsec2" id="affectedsec2">
<div>
<div class="form-group affectedsec3" id="affectedsec3">
<div>
<div class="form-group affectedsec4" id="affectedsec4">
<div>
```

and below is my jquery

```
    $(".noAffected").change(function(){
        var val=$(this).val();
        alert(val);
        for (var i = 1; i < val; i++) 
        {
            alert(i);
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getdata.php",
                data: {i:i},
                cache: false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                $(".affectedsec"+i).html(data);
                }
            });
        }  


    });
```

this ajax can be done by single call of ajax. But im wondering to have a loop in it.. below is my getdata.php

```
$rows = $progs->fetchAll();

    echo '<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Section '.$_POST["i"].'</label>';
    echo '<div class="col-sm-9">';
    echo '<select name="affectsec'.$_POST["i"].'" class="form-control '.$_POST["i"].'" id="affectsec'.$_POST["i"].'" required>';
    echo '<option value="">Section</option>';

foreach($rows as $row)
{ 
    echo '<option value="'.$row['dpt_id'].'" >'.$row['dpt_name'].'</option>';
}
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</div>';
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: the looping for the ajax doesnt works

Comment: your closing <div> tags are incorrect

Comment: Why are you trying to loop on the client side here? Making x separate AJAX requests makes rather little sense, if you ask me. Why do you not just send the _number_ of select fields you want to generate to the server, and then do the loop in PHP? Have it create x such select fields, send the whole HTML back to the client, insert into the document …

Answer (score 1):

Don't loop the `ajax` request. Instead loop inside the `PHP` file.

**HTML:**

```
<select name="noAffected" class="form-control noAffected" id="noAffected" required>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
<script>
$("#noAffected").on('change', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getdata.php",
        data: { value: $(this).val() },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#output").html(data.html);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php $rows = $progs->fetchAll();

ob_start();
    $ctr = 1;
    foreach ($_POST['value'] as $v) { ?>
        <div class="form-group affectedsec<?php echo $ctr; ?>" id="affectedsec<?php echo $ctr; ?>">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Section <?php echo $ctr; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select name="affectsec<?php echo $ctr; ?>" class="form-control <?php echo $ctr; ?>" id="affectsec<?php echo $ctr; ?>" required>
                    <option value="">Section</option>
                    <?php foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['dpt_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['dpt_name']; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>';
        </div>
<?php
    $ctr++;
    }
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// wp_send_json(['html' => $html]); // If using wordpress
echo json_encode(['html' => $html]); // If not using wordpress
```

Comment: Working. And i put another loop of select option because there are another dependent selection for the Section dropdown. once section dropdown selected, another selection will appear again. So everything worked up once add and change the code

Comment: Great, glad I can help.